# View amount of time left when uploading files to iCloud

Tags: icloud

I am currently moving some files to my iCloud drive with the total File Size of 42GB. At the moment I can only see the percentage completed by looking at the progress bar in the Finder. Since this is taking a long time (not surprising), is it possible to view the estimated time remaining?

**Edit:**

Think this will be useful for another time because 42GB uploading with 0.75Mb/s will take >2 months. Answers will still be useful though for another time.

Comment: If the file sizes are small, I wouldn't extrapolate 2 months. I have about 100 GB of storage cached locally (on Server.app - caching) for various iCloud stores in the household. We took days to sync up as opposed to months.

Comment: @bmike are 3 virtual machines that in total are 42GB

Comment: Yeah - that's going to be painful unless you convert them to something like a band based sparse disk image that's more amenable to small chunks remaining static and being amenable to shorter sync sessions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to check all percentages is:

```sh
brctl monitor com.apple.CloudDocs | grep %
```

Possibly some other commands will help as well if the above has too much detail. Open terminal.app and issue the command:

```sh
brctl log -w
```

That will dump all sorts of iCloud sync data and debugging status - most of which won't be relevant, but you can watch it over time to see if any of the internal information allows you to calculate things or just know that something is happening or has had an error.

```sh
brctl status | grep foreground
```

The above command will show active containers and you might be able to monitor the specific container that has activity in a second window:

```sh
brctl monitor com.apple.CloudDocs | grep filename
```

The monitor command could slow things down as it dumps a lot of status to my screen as I have a lot of files in iCloud currently - but it does show periodic % estimates for the specific files being uploaded. Change filename to match a file or folder you want to check on.

*All of the commands that run indefinitely above can be quit with Control + C*

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. Is there a command to view the estimated time remaining?

Comment: @iProgram There is no forecast that I can determine - just a % - you'd have to extrapolate that yourself with a script.